# following statement is true or false?

Tags: real-analysis

let $ f:[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ is continuous and bounded.

then f has a fixed point or not?

now i have two problems.

1) i know fixed point theorem when $f$ is continuous and $f:[a,b] \to [a,b]$ but for unbounded interval i take some examples and result is positive? can anyone help me for unbounded?

2) what if i write  $ f:[0,\infty] \to [0,\infty]$ is continuous and bounded.

is the point 2 makes any sense because along infinity open bracket should come?

Comment: It's obviously true.  There's no way for the graph of $f(x)$ to be completely on top of the graph of $y=x$ if $f$ is bounded and there's no way to be completely under it since $f(0)\geq0$.

Comment: Also, note that many logicians would say that the answer to a question of the form *"Is <P> true or false?"* is *yes.*

Comment: @ClementC.: and also at least one non-logician.  See [my answer to another of OP's questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1656266/is-the-following-statement-true-or-false), written before I saw this one

Answer (score 4):

Consider $g\colon [0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x) = f(x)-x$.

- $g$ is continuous;
- $g(0) = f(0) \geq 0$;
- $\lim_{x\to\infty} g = -\infty$ as $f$ is bounded.

Apply the [Intermediate Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) (IVT) to $g$.

Comment: Clement C. thanks. got it