# is the following statement true or false?

Tags: derivatives, power-series

if $f$ is infinitely  differentiable function such that $f^{k}(0)=$ for all non negative integers k. then f is identically zero or not?

i think it should be zero because of Taylor theorem after expanding it at $x=0$?

Answer (score 3):

I would like to answer the question in your title "Yes", but the site demands more characters.

The statement is false.  Not all functions, even infinitely differentiable ones, can be represented by Taylor series.  The classic example is $$f(x)=\begin {cases} 0& x \le 0\\e^{-\frac 1{x^2}}& x \gt 0 \end {cases}$$

You should be able to convince yourself that the positive part has every derivative approaching zero as $x \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

I think
$e^{-1/x^2}$
or some variant
might be a counterexample.